# How to retrieve and render content from a remote site’s page with Web Api?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am a newbie with WP Web api.

I would like to render the content of a page from a remote site on a page from my site:

[http://www.my-url/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/34/](http://gscourtprobation.nashville.gov/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/34/)

How do I parse, render and embed just the content on a page on my own site? What is needed on my end to do this? Is there a javascript example? or would I need to do this in php?

Thanks in advance for any help….

Answer (score 2):

Got this working as desired using jQuery .ajax function.

On my page where I want the remote site's content rendered, I use the following:

```
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'http://www.my-url/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/34/',
           error: function() {
              $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
           },
           dataType: 'json',
           async: false,
           type: 'GET',  
           success: function(data) {
             var theContent = data;
             document.getElementById("remote-content").innerHTML = theContent.content.rendered; 
           }
        });
        });
        </script>

        <span id="remote-content"></span>
```